# Several values associated with the same categories, Unable to show in a Matrix in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have a data like shown blow, with images associated with column 1 and column 2

The problem: it only show one image; however in the raw data there are 6 images associated with the the same to column. How can I fix this?

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gpp4.png)

I tried to group it but it didn't work out